# Laravel API call form validation not working

Tags: laravel, rest, api

I'm working with Laravel API and calling an API method in two different way. In one-way form validation working but in second-way form validation not working. But I really need second-way of API call.

```
saveMember: function () {
    let that = this;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('member_info', that.member_info);

    // member_info is a Json Object
    // This is First way , form validation working good while calling Api
    axios.post('/api/member/save_member', that.member_info)

    // This is second way, form validation not working
    axios.post('/api/member/save_member', that.formData)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("response Here: " + response.data.success);
            that.errors = response.data.success;
            // location.reload(true);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            that.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            console.log("Error Here: " + error.response.data);
        });
}
```

Doing form validation in Laravel Request Controller.

Comment: What's inside member_info?

Comment: Can you let us know why you need to use `FormData`?

Comment: FormData is using to upload photo at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Look like Json Object can send to API.
I missing your error when request call to fixed.

But i think you need convert FormData to Json Object:

```
var obj = {};
that.formData.forEach(function(val, idx){
    obj[idx] = val;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

and then resend:

```
axios.post('/api/member/save_member', json)
...
```